# MongoDB query AND/OR Precedent

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In MongoDB, if I wanted to express A AND (B OR C), I can easily do by:

```
db.demo.find( { a: 1, $or: [ {b:1}, {c:1} ] });
```

But if I wanted (A AND B) OR C -- it does not seem to work. If I try:

```
db.demo.find( { $or: [ {a:1,b:1}, {c:1} ] });
```

the above is treating it as A or B or C, which is same as

```
db.demo.find( { $or: [ {a:1}, {b:1}, {c:1} ] });
```

At this point in time, I do not want to use Javascript expression $where to accomplish this (but will have no choice, if nothing else works) - the reason being, I am creating a general filter rules, which is being directly converted as MongoDB query.

Any help?

Comment: Oops! No, the question is incorrect. The query works as it should. I have posted the details in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query works actually, exactly as it should. The question is incorrect.

Here is what a view of what I tried and how it works!

Data:

```
> db.demo.find() 
{ "_id" : 1, "age" : 38, "mgmt" : "no", "salary" : 100 } 
{ "_id" : 2, "age" : 45, "salary" : 200, "mgmt" : "no" } 
{ "_id" : 3, "age" : 50, "salary" : 250, "mgmt" : "no" } 
{ "_id" : 4, "age" : 51, "salary" : 75, "mgmt" : "yes" } 
{ "_id" : 5, "age" : 45, "salary" : 75, "mgmt" : "no" }
```

Query to get (Age>40 AND Salary>200) OR mgmt='yes'

```
> db.demo.find( { $or: [ { age: {$gt:40}, salary:{$gt:200} }, {mgmt: 'yes'} ] }) 
{ "_id" : 3, "age" : 50, "salary" : 250, "mgmt" : "no" } 
{ "_id" : 4, "age" : 51, "salary" : 75, "mgmt" : "yes" }
```

Query to get (Age>40) OR (Salary>200) OR mgmt='yes'

```
> db.demo.find( { $or: [ { age: {$gt:40}}, {salary:{$gt:201} }, {mgmt: 'yes'} ] }) 
{ "_id" : 2, "age" : 45, "salary" : 200, "mgmt" : "no" } 
{ "_id" : 3, "age" : 50, "salary" : 250, "mgmt" : "no" } 
{ "_id" : 4, "age" : 51, "salary" : 75, "mgmt" : "yes" } 
{ "_id" : 5, "age" : 45, "salary" : 75, "mgmt" : "no" }
```

All of them working as it should. Great!